# Computer screen turns black when CPU is under load

Tags: windows-10, display, cpu, hardware-failure

Recently, I had assembled a new computer. When I try to render the BMW benchmark from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/), it seems to work well at first and temperatures never exceed 65 degrees celsius. But after a few minutes the screen turns black for a second. Once it comes back I am greeted with a dialogue box stating that blender has crashed. Looking at reliability history shows this error under hardware failure label:[image]

I have tried installing chipset drivers, reinstalling graphics drivers and disabling Turbo Boost.

Components:

i7 8700K (Stock speed)

Corsair - Vengeance LPX 16GB (at 2133 Mhz)

MSI - Z370 SLI PLus ATX LGA1151 Motherboard

Gigabyte GTX 1080 Ti (Stock speed)

Samsung 860 Evo

Seagate FireCuda 2TB

EVGA SuperNOVA G3 850W 80+ Gold

Windows 10 Home (Fresh install on the 860 Evo)

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless CPU is heated only up to 65 degrees I would suggest to disable Intel integrated graphics core, seems like incompatibility with external GTX card.
Anyway it's a graphics issues.

I can also suggest to check GTX card temperatures and [check Event viewer for system issues](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996634(v=exchg.65).aspx). There you may find that graphics driver (Intel or nVidia) failed.

Comment: I followed your advice and the GPU temperature is fine but event viewer shows that the nvidia display driver had stopped responding but the recovered.